# How do I print files in a directory with a numerical index preceding them?

Tags: bash

I’d like to print all files in a directory with a numbering, so that each file has a number before it, like this:

1. myfile.txt
2. anotherfile
3. etc

I then want to refer to these files later on, like this:

mv 1 2 3 directory

How could I refer to the files by a numerical ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the filenames in an indexed array, and use the array indices, ex.

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( * )

for i in ${!files[@]}; do 
  printf '%d. %s\n' $i "${files[i]}"
done
```

To refer to a file via its index `n`, use `"${files[n]}"`, where `n` is evaluated as a numeric expression, ex. `"${files[3]}"` or `n=3; echo "${files[n]}"`. Note that array indices in bash start from 0.

Comment: Thanks. Can I pass multiple indices to that file list? I’d like to conveniently move a bunch of files, like mv “${files[1, 2, 4:10, 22]}” directory. Or enter a live shell where I can just type “$ 1 2 4-10 directory”, without typing the “files”.

Comment: @PeterElbert you'd need to write a custom move command (shell function) that maps its arguments back to filenames I think (there's no way for the shell - or mv - to know that `1`, `2` and `4-10` are not filenames)

Comment: What do ! and @ do, in the above?

Comment: @PeterElbert `${files[@]}` expands to a list of array values; whereas `${!files[@]}` expands to a list of the array's indices (or keys, in the case of an associative array). See the `Arrays` subsection under the `PARAMETERS` section of `man bash`.